# Transiting in the US with multiple carriers on a C1 visa

Tags: visas, usa, customs-and-immigration, transit, layovers

I am an Indian national flying Tokyo-Honolulu-LA-Havana with different airlines with a US C1 transit visa.

1. Will Scoot Airlines, when flying from Tokyo to Honolulu, create any problems as I don't have any other boarding passes yet, and for them my final destination is Honolulu? I hold a C1 visa, not a B1/B2.
2. Will the immigration official in Honolulu ask for boarding passes for my final destination, as online check-in only opens 24 hours in advance and my transit it more than 24 hours?

Comment: I'm curious if in your part of the world, boarding passes are usually required, rather than confirmations? As you point out, that would be challenging if check-in hasn't opened yet

Answer (score 4):

You should not be required to have boarding passes.  Your ticket should be sufficient.  A C-1 visa is valid for transits of up to 29 days ([8 CFR 214.2(c)(3)](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/8/214.2#c_3)), so requiring boarding passes would be impractical.

Comment: @Kumar You don't need boarding passes at immigration, and you can leave the airport too.